# How to return a table of values from a function in oracle

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, user-defined-types

I have tried some of the answers and could not make my code work:
Here is what I want and here is what I did:
I have a table which is two column type and I want to query that table using a function to return exactly the same table to be routed to VB.NET so that I can display it in a DatagridView control.
I am a novice to PL/SQL which is the problem for me.
The first problem I intended to solve is to create the function.

```
-- DECLARE A RECORD TYPE
create or replace type shipper_type AS OBJECT
(
shipper_id number,  shipper_name varchar2(7)
);
/

CREATE TYPE t_shipper as table of shipper_type;
/

    create or replace function get_shipper return t_shipper is 
    temp_list t_shipper:= t_shipper();
    is  
     --  shipper_record shipper_type;
    begin
      for i in (  (select shipper.shipper_id, shipper.shipper_name) list from shipper) 
      loop
        temp_list.extend;
      temp_list(temp_list.last):= t_shipper(list);   
    end loop;

    return(temp_list);
   end get_shipper;
   /
```

When I try to compile this code I am getting the following errors:
Errors for FUNCTION GET_SHIPPER:

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
3/1      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IS" when expecting one of the
         following:
         begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>
         <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete
         exists prior

6/63     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the
         following:
         . ( , * @ % & - + / at mod remainder rem <an identifier>
         <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <an exponent (**)> as
         from || multiset
```

Answer (score 2):

You get those compilation messages because you have several syntax errors in your code.  Two instances of `IS`, missing the type in the `select`, those unnecessary brackets in the `return`.    You can correct those but you should simplify your code too.

The easiest way to populate a nested table is with a bulk collect.

```
create or replace function get_shipper return t_shipper is 
    temp_list t_shipper:= t_shipper();
begin
    select shipper_type(shipper.shipper_id, shipper.shipper_name) 
    bulk collect into temp_list
    from shipper;

    return temp_list ;
end get_shipper;
/
```

Comment: If this solved your problem you should accept it as the correct solution.  [Find out how](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

Try it without () in the return statement and add an end; at the end.

```
return temp_list; 

end;
```

Also you might want to take a look at so called pipelined functions:
http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/pipelined-table-functions.php